# R Shiny - Using a custom message handler to disable a single radio button in a radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

The app below contains a selectInput `input$set1` with two options (`download` and `upload`) and a radio button group `input$set2` that is rendered using `renderUI()`. I am using a custom message handler that disables a radio button in the radio button group depending on the value of the selectInput (if `input$set1 == 'download'` then disable the `upload` radio button and enable it otherwise).

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

toggleRadioOpt <- function(session, inputId, choice, enable = TRUE, selected) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(
    type = 'toggleRadioOpt',
    message = list(id = inputId, choice = choice, enable = enable, selected = selected)
  )
}

modUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(

    tags$head(
      tags$script("

                  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('toggleRadioOpt',
                  function(data) {
                  $('#' + data.id + ' input[value = \"' + data.choice + '\"]').attr('disabled', !data.enable).prop('checked', false);
    if(data.selected !== null) {
                  $('#' + data.id + ' input[value = \"' + data.selected + '\"]').prop('checked', true);
}
                  }
                  );

                  ")
      ),

    prettyRadioButtons(ns('set1'), label = 'Select', choices = c('download', 'upload', 'abb')),

    # selectInput(ns('set1'), label = 'Select', choices = c('download', 'upload', 'sql')),

    uiOutput(ns('taskUI'))

      )

}


modServer <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  ns = session$ns

  output$taskUI <- renderUI({

    switch(input$set1, 
           'download' = selectInput(ns('data'), '', state.area),
           'upload' = selectInput(ns('data'), '', state.center),
           'abb' = tagList(
             selectInput(ns('data'), '', state.abb), 
             actionButton(ns('upload'), 'Upload')
             )
           )

    prettyRadioButtons(ns('set2'), label = '', choices = c('split', 'upload'))

  })

  observe({

    if(!is.null(input$set2)) {

      if(input$set1 %in% c('download', 'abb')) {

        toggleRadioOpt(session = session, inputId = ns('set2'), choice = 'upload', enable = F, selected = 'split')

      } else {

        toggleRadioOpt(session = session, inputId = ns('set2'), choice = 'upload', enable = T, selected = 'split')

      }

    }

  })
})


# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
ui = fluidPage(modUI('first'))

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(modServer, 'first')  

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The handler works as expected if the radio button group is created in the UI but fails if the buttons are created using `renderUI()`. Specifically, it fails on startup but then works if `input$set1` is changed subsequently. I am new to using custom message handlers so I'm not sure what's going on here or how to fix it. I thought it may have something to do with the jQuery being triggered before the UI has loaded but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it may have something to do with the jQuery being triggered
>   before the UI has loaded but I can't be sure.

I think so. Before the UI has loaded, `input$set2` is `NULL`. You can do:

```
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$set2)){
      if(input$set1 == 'download') {
        toggleRadioOpt(session = session, inputId = ns('set2'), choice = 'upload',
                       enable = F, selected = 'split')
      } else {
        toggleRadioOpt(session = session, inputId = ns('set2'), choice = 'upload', 
                       enable = T, selected = 'split')
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: This works if I only render `set2` within the `renderUI` but not if multiple elements are rendered conditional on the value of `set1`. I have edited my post to show an example of this, would it please be possible to have a look? Adding the other elements to the if statement did not work. I resorted to putting the `toggleRadioOpt(...)` in a `shinyjs::delay()` with an arbitrary delay. This works but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.